# Pulling Elasticsearch Docker images for previous versions

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm working on a project that uses and older version of Elasticsearch, so I'd like to adapt the instructions at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/docker.html#_pulling_the_image to pull a lower-version image.

I can see there is a `2.4.5` tag available on Elasticsearch's Docker Hub:

[image]

However, if I try to download 2.4.3 (which is also there), I get this 'manifest not found' error:

```
> docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:2.4.3
Error response from daemon: manifest for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:2.4.3 not found
```

Is this not the right way to specify the tag name in order to pull that version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: `docker pull elasticsearch:2.4.3` worked for me. The command mentioned in the site is `docker pull elasticsearch` which pulls the docker image with latest tag. Since you want specific version you should do `docker pull elasticsearch:2.4.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are watching this version in docker hub but pulling image from a docker repository hosted by [elastic.co](https://www.docker.elastic.co/#) rather than docker hub. [elastic.co](https://www.docker.elastic.co/#) docker repository's last version is `5.2.1` (according to current date and this may change) so if you want to pull more lower version, you have to pull it from docker hub

```
docker pull elasticsearch:2.4.3
```

This will pull `2.4.3` version from docker hub.